# iterate list and remove items from it in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

Objective-c have a built-in list iterantor via 'for(a in b) syntax that works fine with NSArray and other collections. But is it possible to remove items during such iteration without ugly tricks like

```
for( int i = 0, i < [array count]; i ++ )
{
  if( condition )
  {
    [array removeItemAtIndex : i];
    i --;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can iterate array in the reverse order so you won't need to extra adjust index:

```
for( int i = [array count]-1; i >=0; --i)
{
   if( condition )
   {
      [array removeItemAtIndex : i];
   }
}
```

Or accumulate indexes  to delete in indexset while enumerating and then delete all elements at once:

```
NSMutableIndexSet *indexes = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
for( int i = 0, i < [array count]; i ++ )
{
  if( condition )
  {
    [indexes addIndex : i];
  }
}
[array removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexes];
[indexes release];
```

I would choose 2nd option because changing array while enumerating may be not a good style (although it won't give you errors in this particular case)

Comment: I think your second answer would be the "official" prettiest way to do it. Although your first answer is better in my opinion. They both probably work the same way.

Comment: 2nd way may be (intuitively) also more efficient because you remove elements at once, plus as Ole Bergeman said altering collection while enumerating it is generally not a good idea - you will get an error if you mutate collection while "fast enumerating" it.

Comment: The for loop in the first answer has a comma instead of a semicolon. No big deal but I just copied the code and saw that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

No, mutating a collection while enumerating it is explicitly forbidden. You could add the objects that should be removed to a second temporary mutable array and then, outside the loop, remove the objects in that array from the original with `removeObjectsInArray:`.

Comment: ...is explicitly forbidden *when using Fast Enumeration*.  Granted that it's not a good idea to do it when using a normal `for()` loop, but it's allowed.

Comment: @Dave: not only Fast Enumeration. Using standard NSEnumerators is also "not safe". So as I see it, mutating a collection while _enumerating_ it is indeed forbidden while it is okay to do so while _iterating_ over it.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't Call it a dirty trick to iterate backwards through the array.
for(int i=array.count-1;i>=0;i--)
  if(condition)
     [array removeItemAtIndex:i];

Answer (score 1):

If I need it I copy my array and enumerate one while the other is mutating

```
NSArray *arr = firstArr;
for( int i = [array count]-1, i >=0; --i)
{
   if( condition )
   {
      [firstArr removeItemAtIndex : i];
   }
}
```

but I think Vladimir's example is the better one ;) (just to have all possibilities)