# Statusbar menu item delete behaviour

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am adding some menu items to my statusbar menu and removing some of them afterwards before opening the menu. 
This looks like this in code:

```
for(int i = 4; i <= 20; i++) {
    [menu insertItemWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d. Menuitem", i] action:nil         keyEquivalent:@"" atIndex:i];
}

for(int j = 10; j <= 14; j++) {
    [menu removeItemAtIndex:j];
}
```

But the result looks like this:
[image: menu result]

It seems to delete every second item, but the console logs are looking fine (Number of menu items, i, j).

> removed item at index: 10 with title: "11. Menuitem"
>   removed item at index: 11 with title: "13. Menuitem"
>   removed item at index: 12 with title: "15. Menuitem"
>   removed item at index: 13 with title: "17. Menuitem"
>   removed item at index: 14 with title: "19. Menuitem"

Is there anything to do for refreshing the indices or something like that?

Comment: Please copy your code in the question, instead of using a barely readable screenshot.

Comment: sorry Guillaume. I've just updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't delete items from an array you are iterating on. In the best case scenario, you have out of sync indexes with the values you expected to delete, in the worst case you'll crash.

In general, you could either decrement the index (`j`) when deleting an element, or build a list of indexes to delete and delete all the elements at once after the loop.

see [iterate list and remove items from it in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480556/iterate-list-and-remove-items-from-it-in-objective-c)

In your case, you could probably do something like:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    [menu removeItemAtIndex:10];
}
```

*(untested)*

Comment: Thanks a lot! I haven't thought about the index-structure. The other elements are filling out the deleted ones like sand :D